# how to write numbers in lambda using ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am new to Haskell, using Ghci.

I have a function, called three, that I want to write as

```
let three =  \x->(\y->(x(x(x y))))
```

OK, this works, but when I try

```
three (2+) 4
```

It does not work. Instead, I get some "cannot construct infinite type" error.

Please help me.

Comment: You should post the exact error message. I can't reproduce it in GHC 6.10.4, it works there.

Comment: Can't reproduce either. What version GHC/post the full transcript.

Comment: Prelude> let three = \x->(\y->(x(x(x y))))
Prelude> :type three
three :: (t -> t) -> t -> t
Prelude> three (2+) 4
10

Comment: You could also write three better as

three f = f.f.f

Comment: Or `three = foldr (.) id . replicate 3`, if you want to be pointless, err, point-free.

Comment: This should work just fine given `three :: (a -> a) -> a -> a`, and will fail if you pass it a function `a -> b`.

Answer (score 6):

```
ghci> let three = \x->(\y->(x(x(x y))))
ghci> three (2+) 4
10
ghci> three return "deconstructivist"

<interactive>:1:6:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t = m t
      Expected type: t
      Inferred type: m t
    In the first argument of 'three', namely 'return'
    In the expression: three return "deconstructivist"
ghci> :t three
three :: (t -> t) -> t -> t
ghci> :t return
return :: (Monad m) => a -> m a
```

- The example you supplied of `three (2+) 4`, works! Better check that the examples you provide actually reproduce your problem.
- As for with a different example, like the one above with `return`, the thing is that return results in a different type than the one given. If the type was the same, it would be infinite (and of kind `* -> * -> * -> ...`), which Haskell does not support.

Answer (score 0):

The example you give does work. Let's explain why:

```
three f = f . f . f
-- so...
three :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

The function needs to have type `a -> a` because it will receive it's own argument, which requires a type. `(2+)` has type `Num a => a -> a`, so `three (2+) 4` will work just fine.

However, when you pass a function like `return` of type `Monad m => a -> m a`, which returns a different type, it will not match the `(a -> a)` requirement we set out. This is where and when your function will fail.

While you're at it, try making a function like `doTimes` with type `Integer -> (a -> a) -> a -> a` which does the given function the given number of times - it's a good next step after making this function.